# System.out.println() shortcut doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have newest Eclipse version installed on my laptop. When I try to use shortcut "syso" for `System.out.println()` (I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>) i get two new windows like this:

[image: Eclipse - two windows syso]

But on my older laptop, when I click same combinations of keyboard buttons, I instantly get `System.out.println()` without any questions like on the added picture.

I tried compare Eclipse settings between two computers, but there are huge number of preferences to configure under Eclipse. I open *Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates* and found sysout, then clicked edit, but settings are same. 
Can someone help me, please?
Many thanks,
Java begginer

EDIT: I found on older laptop (and Eclipse version) there is no syso template, only sysout, but both working
On new laptop same template, only working sysout

Comment: In newer eclipse if you write `Map` and then `ctrl-space`. it will show `ManagementPermission` as one of the suggestions.

Comment: Where I must write Map?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this

```
Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates
```

be confirm you have only one entry for `syso` in template menu.

Also check what code is written for me this shortcut is there

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply! I can't find template menu: http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2015/10/03/Screen Shot 10-03-15 at 08.png   (

Comment: I  changed the location

Comment: We have the same shortcut code System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}

Comment: I doesn't have entry for syso, only for sysout

Comment: then type `sysout`  and then `CTRL+SPACE` otherwise make a entry

Comment: What I can write in pattern of new entry?

Comment: No `sysout` and then `CTRL+SPACE` giving you full `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 1):

actually the keys you should use is (sout) then click on (tab) bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you have to type sysout then click CTRL+space

Comment: Thanks for reply! When I type sysout on new laptop it works fine (without two windows). But I can type both syso and sysout on older laptop without two windoes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to file--->preferences--->user snippets
2. Search for 'java.json' then include this line and save.

   "sout": {
   "prefix": "sout",
   "body": ["System.out.println("$1");"],
   "description": "print new line"
   },